# Do I use WeakReference correctly

Tags: java, weak-references

I am building a javaagent, which help people to find leaked JDBC connections.

When client code creates a connection, my agent will record the stacktrace which called to create that connection, the time creation happens, and also makes a weak reference to that connection instance. When client code use that connection, my agent will update a "lastActiveTime" timestamp, when client code closes the connection, I am going to clear record.

By doing so, the user can observe connection stats. And when the user can tell a connection was leaked, they can close it by getting that instance from the weak reference.

As a connection instance may last a long time, the weak reference won't prevent it be GCed, when it was closed by client code normally.

Is my design valid?

Comment: Have you considered what happens if a connection was not closed, but no code is referencing it anymore: your weak reference is cleared and the connection is GC'ed? Are you OK with that?

Comment: You say “*when client code closes the connection, I am going to clear record*” and then “*the weak reference won't prevent it be GCed, when it was closed by client code normally*” but when you clear the reference on normal `close()` anyway, the weak nature of the reference is irrelevant. When you stop referencing the connection after `close()`, it can get collected anyway. As Mark Rotteveel said, a weak reference allows the collection *even if `close()` has not been called*, which is the whole point of weak refs, as that’s the way you determine that the client code won’t call `close()` at all.

Comment: @Holger you mean a connection instance not  referenced anymore and got GC'ed while `close()` not called, so my weak reference can't get that instance any more ? If I understand it correctly, I think I need to go with real reference

Comment: As said, the actual criteria to be sure that the application will do neither, use nor close the collection in the future, is the fact that the connection became unreachable. The only way to detect this and be able to perform the missing close call, is to hand out a proxy `Connection` to the application, instead of the real one. So when the proxy became unreachable, you can call close on the real one. However, most implementations do some equivalent action anyway. You should focus on emitting the warning for missing `close()` calls rather than performing it after the fact.